# Dark Nav Background on Homepage and Invert on Subpages?

Tags: website-design, navigation, design, user-research, ux-designer

from a design or UI/UX perspective:

I have a homepage, the header is dark and so is the navigation bar. Background of the nav is a dark color; logo and text is white.

On sub pages, the Nav is inverted, meaning the background is white and the text color and logo is a dark color.

I received some feedback that this is supposed to be a nogo, but I haven't seen anything on that topic that supports my stand nor for the other side.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

It's not consistent, and consistency is often mentioned as one of the key points in UX design (e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@digitalofthings/ux-principle-9-consistency-clarity-and-standards-6ab2a62f52b6)). You don't want your users to think that they ended up on another site, unless they did; compare e.g. the dark navigation bar of this site:

[image: UX.SE navigation bar]

with the light one of Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow navigation bar]